# Real Time Data Capture System

Tags: digital-logic, adc, communication, memory

I would like to build a system which could capture an analogue waveform data in real time. For the basic data acquisition system I can use an ADC to digitise an analogue waveform and store this in a memory buffer.

However, when I have to read the data out of the memory, I can no longer write data in. This will give me a break in my data acquisition.

What I would like is some memory which would allow one location to be read whilst reading from another. I understand this probably doesn't exist, but I am sure real time data capture does.

So how do they do it?

Do they use two memory chips, and write to one whilst reading from the other with some VERY careful timing controlling the switch over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such memory does exist, it is called Dual Port RAM (DPRAM).